# parsing html <script> via PHP isn't working completely

Tags: php, javascript, smarty, template-engine

I find this very strange, must be something I'm doing wrong, but still...
I'm working on a page using PHP and TPL files.
In my TPL file, there's a place in the footer for some extra lines if needed.

For instance, formchecking with Javascript.

so in PHP I did this:

```
$foot = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">if(document.getElementById){loadEvents();}</script>";
```

the $foot  variable is then parsed and the result in HTML is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if(document.getElementById)</script>
```

So `{loadEvents();}` went missing.

Does anybody see what I'm missing here... I'm seriously not finding it. Did I forget to escape a character or something?

Comment: by TPL files do you mean Smarty? How is the $foot getting into the tpl file?

Comment: Maybe telling people that you use a template engine instead of letting them guess would have been a nice thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously the [template engine you are using](http://www.smarty.net/) eats away the part in curly braces.

Try something like:

```
$foot = "{literal}<script type=\"text/javascript\">if(document.getElementById){loadEvents();}</script>{/literal}";
```

Comment: not working, I also noticed that the last quotation mark in your solution is a double, fixed that, still not working

Comment: Yes. Seen that too late, fixed.

Comment: -1 because this is simply not true  echo "{1+1}"; will not output "2".  The {} within double quotes is only used for disambiguating variables, e.g. "he drank some {$beer}s."  The issue here is most likely the templating engine, in which case a fix would depend on which engine was in use.

Comment: This isn't correct - the $foot = "<script... etc. line evaluates correctly

Comment: That there was a template engine involved was not clear to me. Should have thought of that though.

Comment: template engine or not, "1 + 1 = {1+1}" doesn't evaluate as "1 + 1 = 2"

Comment: True, but since I had to change my answer completely anyway, this is no longer relevant.

Comment: removed -1, but I'm not sure that smarty would parse a variable that was created in PHP anyway. surely it would only parse .tpl files.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a template engine like Smarty, which tries to parse anything it finds within braces.

[This page](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.escaping.php) from the smarty documentation explains how to make smarty ignore sections it would otherwise parse.

Answer (score 1):

I believe with {} that PHP is expecting a variable within them. I haven't tested this, but try using single quote instead of double-quotes.

Comment: -1 because php doesn't parse {var} as a variable. It uses $var, ${var}, or {$var}

Comment: I didn't say {var} ... ? All I said is that it expects a variable; in which case yes it would be along the lines of {$var}

Answer (score 1):

If you are using smarty you could use the {literal}.

[literal](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.literal.php)